# Flutter TextFormField Validation is not Showing, And it gives Errors of inactive InputConnections

Tags: android-studio, flutter, uitextfield, flutter-layout

So, I have been searching a way to resolve the issue of Flutter TextFormField not showing the Validator's Error Message.
here is my code for my signUp screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:messenger/widgets/widget.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {

  final formKey= GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController usernameTextEditingController= new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailTextEditingController= new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordTextEditingController= new TextEditingController();

  String value;

  bool isLoading=false;

  signMeUp(){
    if(formKey.currentState.validate()){
      setState(() {
        isLoading=true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: isLoading?Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                stops: [0.1,0.5,0.8,1],
                colors: [Colors.yellow,Colors.orangeAccent,Colors.deepOrange, Colors.redAccent]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),):Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            stops: [0.1,0.3,0.7,1],
            colors: [Colors.yellow,Colors.orangeAccent,Colors.deepOrange, Colors.redAccent]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val){
                      return val.isNotEmpty || val.length < 4 ? val="Username is not valid":val =null;
                    },

                    autofocus: false,
                    controller: usernameTextEditingController,
                    style: textFieldTextStyle(),
                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("Username"),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (val){
                      return RegExp(r'^.+@[a-zA-Z]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)$').hasMatch(val)? null:"Email Id is not valid";
                    },
                    autofocus: false,
                    controller: emailTextEditingController,
                    style: textFieldTextStyle(),
                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("Email"),
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: (val){
                      return val.length>6?null:"Password should be greater than 6 characters";
                    },
                    controller: passwordTextEditingController,
                    style: textFieldTextStyle(),
                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("Password"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15,),
            Container(
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16,vertical: 8),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Text("By clicking Sign Up, you agree to our Policies",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 13,fontWeight: FontWeight.w300))),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 15,),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                signMeUp();
              },
              child: Container(
                  child: buttonToUse("Sign Up",Colors.orangeAccent)
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 4,),
            Container(
                child: buttonToUse("Sign Up with Google",Colors.lightBlueAccent)
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Already have an Account?  ",style: textFieldTextStyle(),),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: Text("Sign In",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 16,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      decoration: TextDecoration.underline)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and the error i face while typing something in those form fields

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): setComposingRegion on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(10562): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
```

plus, i dont see any validator error on my app here is a screen shot
[There is no red lines showing the error even after pressing the sign Up buttom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91CGN.png)

btw it would be nice if i can get your views on a better ui

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `autovalidate` property of the form to `true`, if you want the validation errors to be shown while the user is typing.

Regarding the state of your UI, I wouldn't advise replacing the whole view with the loading indicator when `isLoading` is `true`. I would advise that you change the signup button instead. If you want the whole screen to be inaccessible when it is loading, you would have to use a Heads Up Display dialog of sorts. That will make the whole screen visible, but the user won't be able to interact with the form elements.
You can checkout this library [modal_progress_hud](https://pub.dev/packages/modal_progress_hud)

Also, considering the gradient that you're using, using the default red color to show the error text, might not be best, experiment with a few other colors that improve the visibility of the error messages

Comment: Thanks a lot but i want the loading screen to be customized here is the package i use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit , is there a way to make the background transparent.

Comment: The modal_progress_hud package has on option that will allow you to set the progress indicator widget. So you can use the two packages together. By default the background should be transparent if you use the modal_progress_hud package